# How to Convert Html code to RDLC?

Tags: html, rdlc

I have a Html Code i want to convert it as `rdlc` code format is it possible?

Is there Any Tool is available?

I dont know anything about `rdlc`

Comment: You mean `rdlc` as that reporting stuff from sql server?

Comment: @vinoth answered, please check

Answer (score 0):

The **ReportViewer** control supports a local processing mode that allows you to run client report definition *(.rdlc)* files using the built-in processing capability of the control. The client reports that you run in local processing mode can be easily created in your application project. There are four approaches to creating the report, 
start learning about rdlc from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252067.aspx)

read [this](http://webapplication02.blogspot.in/2011/01/display-html-in-rdlc-file.html) about html-rdlc conversion, there is no specific tools for that, but may be you can create.